# Scrape Each Table from Drop Down Menu Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape Division 3 College Basketball stats from the following NCAA stats page:

https://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/change_sport_year_div

To get to the page I am on, after clicking the link, Select Sport = Men's Basketball, Year = 2019-2020, and Div = III

Upon clicking the link, there is a dropdown above the top left corner table. It is labeled "Additional Stats". For each stat there is a table which you can get an excel file of, but I want to be more efficient. I was thinking there could be a way to iterate through the dropdown bar using BeautifulSoup (or perhaps even pd.read_html) to get a dataframe for every stat listed. Is there a way to do this? Going through each stat manually, downloading the excel file, and reading the excel file into pandas would be a pain. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion, to use a combination of `requests`, `beautifulsoup` and a great html table parser from [Scott Rome](https://srome.github.io/Parsing-HTML-Tables-in-Python-with-BeautifulSoup-and-pandas/)(I modified a bit the `parse_html_table` function to remove `\n` and strip whitespaces).

First, you can see  when you inspect the source code of the page that it takes the form : `"https://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/national_ranking?academic_year=2020.0&division=3.0&ranking_period=110.0&sport_code=MBB&stat_seq=145.0"`
for instance for the stat 145 ie "Scoring Offense".

You can therefore use the following code on each of these urls by replacing the `145.0` with values corresponding to the different stats, which you can see when you inspect the source code of the page.

```
# <option value="625">3-pt Field Goal Attempts</option>
# <option value="474">Assist Turnover Ratio</option>
# <option value="216">Assists Per Game</option>
# ...
```

For a specific stat, here for instance scoring offense, you can use the following code to extract the table as a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


el = "https://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/national_ranking?academic_year=2020.0&division=3.0&ranking_period=110.0&sport_code=MBB&stat_seq=145.0"
page = requests.get(el).content.decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
ta = soup.find_all('table', {"id": "rankings_table"})

# Scott Rome function tweaked a bit
def parse_html_table(table):
    n_columns = 0
    n_rows = 0
    column_names = []

    # Find number of rows and columns
    # we also find the column titles if we can
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):

        # Determine the number of rows in the table
        td_tags = row.find_all('td')
        if len(td_tags) > 0:
            n_rows += 1
            if n_columns == 0:
                # Set the number of columns for our table
                n_columns = len(td_tags)

        # Handle column names if we find them
        th_tags = row.find_all('th')
        if len(th_tags) > 0 and len(column_names) == 0:
            for th in th_tags:
                column_names.append(th.get_text())

    # Safeguard on Column Titles
    if len(column_names) > 0 and len(column_names) != n_columns:
        raise Exception("Column titles do not match the number of columns")

    columns = column_names if len(column_names) > 0 else range(0, n_columns)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns,
                      index=range(0, n_rows))
    row_marker = 0
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        column_marker = 0
        columns = row.find_all('td')
        for column in columns:
            df.iat[row_marker, column_marker] = column.get_text()
            column_marker += 1
        if len(columns) > 0:
            row_marker += 1

    # remove \n
    for col in df:
        try:
            df[col] = df[col].str.replace("\n", "")
            df[col] = df[col].str.strip()
        except ValueError:
            pass
    # Convert to float if possible
    for col in df:
        try:
            df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return df


example = parse_html_table(ta[0])
```

The result is

```
 Rank                           Team    GM    W-L    PTS    PPG
0    1             Greenville (SLIAC)  27.0  14-13  3,580  132.6
1    2  Grinnell (Midwest Conference)  25.0  13-12  2,717  108.7
2    3             Pacific (OR) (NWC)  25.0   7-18  2,384   95.4
3    4                  Whitman (NWC)  28.0   20-8  2,646   94.5
4    5            Valley Forge (ACAA)  22.0  12-11  2,047   93.0
...
```

Now, what you have to do is apply this to all stat values mentioned above.

You can make a function of the code above, and apply it in a for loop to the url `"https://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/national_ranking?academic_year=2020.0&division=3.0&ranking_period=110.0&sport_code=MBB&stat_seq={}".format(stat)` where `stat` is in list of all possible values.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more concise way to do this :

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0)     Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"}
params = {"sport_code": "MBB", "stat_seq": "518", "academic_year": "2020.0",  "division":"3.0", "ranking_period":"110.0"}
url = "https://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/national_ranking"

resp = rq.post(url, headers=headers, params=params)
soup = bs(resp.content)

colnames = [th.text.strip() for th in soup.find_all("thead")[0].find_all("th")]
data = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in soup.find_all('tbody')[0].find_all("tr")]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=colnames)
df.astype({"GM": 'int32'}).dtypes # convert column in type u want
```

You have to look at the XHR requests [on Mozilla: F12 -> Network -> XHR].

When you select an item from the dropdown list, this makes a post Request through the following url: *https://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/national_ranking*.

Some params are required to make this post request, one of them is "stat_seq". The value corresponds to the "value" of dropdown options.

Inspector give you the list of "value"-StatName correspondence :

```
<option value="625" selected="selected">3-pt Field Goal Attempts</option>
<option value="474">Assist Turnover Ratio</option>
<option value="216">Assists Per Game</option>
<option value="214">Blocked Shots Per Game</option>
<option value="859">Defensive Rebounds per Game</option>
<option value="642">Fewest Fouls</option>
...
...
...
```